# how to determine which combinations of x values produce similar y values?

Tags: classification, clustering

I would like some advice please on a stats problem I am facing.

I have a response variable $y$ and a set of explanatory variables $x_1, x_2, \dots x_6$. All variables are quantitative.

My client is aiming to collapse $y$ into a small number of subsets (the number is not known for sure but perhaps 5) with each subset having "small" variance within, and each of those subsets being determined from the $x$ variables. Ideally, a linear combination (or a couple of linear combinations) of the $x$ variables could produce a single value that is then used to produce a classification of $y$, where each of those $y$ subsets have small variance. We do not know before what the groups in $y$ are,
so based on the values of $x_1,\dots,x_6$ we might produec a variable $z_1$ (or even two variables, say $z_1$ and $z_2$) which we use to classify $y$ into some groups with small within-group variance.

In other words I guess, what combinations of the $x$s produce very similar values for the $y$s.

I'm not even sure what that type of problem is to go searching for information. It sounds a bit like factor analysis but that just produces sets of the $x$s and doesnt even use the $y$.

Comment: This sounds like it could share properties of an optimal stratification problem - for this you can see literature on Lavallee-Hidiroglou, but I'm no expert in this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds much like Piecewise Regression to me. It's like regression but with multiple segments. It's not exactly what you asked for, because the segments may exhibit a linear relationship, not just a constant y.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression